# Page number hyperlinks for subsections from ToC work fine with memoir, hyperref, and \headstyle{wilsondob}, but not with \headstyle{dowding}

Tags: hyperref, memoir

Clicking on page number hyperlinks for subsections from table of contents (ToC) works fine for the {wilsondob} and {tandh} header styles in documentclass memoir, but do not work for {dowding}, when sections work ok but subsections jump you to the top of the pdf.

I am not sure if this is a bug with \headstyles{dowding}, as the problem is fixed when switching to \headstyles{wilsondob} or \headstyles{tandh}.

I've outlined my thesis structure below - am I missing something?

Many thanks

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside, onecolumn, openright, final]{memoir} 

\raggedbottom
\pagestyle{Ruled} %ruled sometimes has pagenumber clash with figure legend
\settrims{0pt}{0pt}
\setlrmargins{3.5cm}{*}{*} 
\checkandfixthelayout

\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{multibib}
\usepackage[sort,round,authoryear]{natbib} 
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[final]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{grffile}
\usepackage{pgf} 
\usepackage{tikz} %requires install.packages('tikzDevice') in R
\usepackage{xfrac} %syntax is \sfrac{}{}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[version=4]{mhchem}
\usepackage{gensymb} 
\usepackage{siunitx} 
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{csvsimple}
\usepackage[left]{lineno}
\usepackage{xcolor} 
\usepackage{xr}
\externaldocument{Chapter01_20190703}
\externaldocument{Chapter02_20190322}
\externaldocument{Chapter03_20190703}
\externaldocument{Chapter04_20190703}
\externaldocument{Chapter05_20190703}
\externaldocument{Chapter06_20190703}
\externaldocument{Chapter07_20181210}
\externaldocument{Chapter08_20190611}
\externaldocument{Chapter0A_20190519}

\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktocpage=true,
    breaklinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=black,
    citecolor=blue}

\usepackage[nonumberlist, nopostdot, nogroupskip, automake]{glossaries} 
\glsdisablehyper
\setacronymstyle{long-short}
\makeglossaries
\loadglsentries{defns}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter 
\include{Titlepage_20190703}

\headstyles{wilsondob} 

\include{Declaration_20181102}
\clearforchapter
\include{Abstract_20190703}
\include{Publications_20190703}
\clearforchapter

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\settocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents

\vfill
\listoffigures
\vfill
\listoftables

\setglossarystyle{long}
\printglossary[type=\acronymtype,title=List of Abbreviations]
\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{List of Abbreviations}
\include{Acknowledgements_20190703}

%Mainmatter
\mainmatter
\pagenumbering{arabic} 
\DoubleSpacing 
\include{Chapter01_20190703}
\include{Chapter02_20190322} 
\include{Chapter03_20190703}
\include{Chapter04_20190703}
\include{Chapter05_20190703}
\include{Chapter06_20190703}
\include{Chapter07_20181210}
\include{Chapter08_20190611}    
\include{Chapter0A_20190519}

%Backmatter
\backmatter 
\SingleSpacing
\bibliographystyle{apa}
\bibliography{../../BibTeX/library}

\end{document}
```

Shortened to:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper, twoside, onecolumn, openright, final]{memoir} 
\usepackage{lipsum}
\PassOptionsToPackage{hyperfootnotes=false}{hyperref}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{memhfixc}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks=true,
    linktocpage=true,
    breaklinks=true,
    urlcolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue,
    citecolor=blue}

\begin{document}

%\headstyles{wilsondob}  
\headstyles{dowding}

\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3} 
\settocdepth{subsection}
\tableofcontents


\chapter{Introduction}
\section{Overview of mechanisms of hypertrophy}
\lipsum[20]
\subsection{Physiological hypertrophy}
\lipsum[20]
\subsection{Pathological hypertrophy}
\lipsum[20]
\subsubsection{Transcriptional players}
\lipsum[20]
\subsubsection{Substrate utilization}
\lipsum[20]
\paragraph{Fat}
Fat oxidation. 
\paragraph{Glucose}
Glucose oxidation.
\chapter{Methods}
\section{EM}
\lipsum[20]
\subsection{Subsec1}
\lipsum[20]
\subsection{Subsec2}
\lipsum[20]
\subsubsection{SS1}
\lipsum[20]
\subsubsection{SS2}
\lipsum[20]
\paragraph{Fat2}
Fat oxidation.
\paragraph{Glucose2}
Glucose oxidation. 

\end{document}
```

Comment: this document can not be tested because of the local documents and is much too large. Create a small, complete test document.

Comment: I've tested a shortened version and cannot replicate the problem. Looks like the problem is not in \headerstyle{dowding}. Thank you for the suggestion!